# Passing values from servlet to jsp

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, jsp, servlets

I'm going to implement a searching function for a sms managing system, where the user can enter a name(keyword) and get relevant information.

This is the code that i wrote in "InstantSMS.jsp"

---

```
  $("#search").click(function() {

        var keyword = $("#customerName").val();
        $.ajax({

            type : "GET",
            url : "SearchingClass",
            data : {
                key : keyword
            }

        }).success(function() {

            $.getJSON('SearchingClass', function(data) {

              $("#resultTable").html(data.messageRes);
            });


        })

        .error(function(request, error) {

            $().toastmessage('showWarningToast', "Error! ");
        });

    });
```

---

Here the 'SearchingClass' is the name of the servlet.
this is the code of 'SearchingClass.java'

---

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
throws ServletException, IOException {

    String keyword = request.getParameter("key");
    SmsMessagesService search = new SmsMessagesService();
    ArrayList<Customers> result = new ArrayList<Customers>();
    System.out.println("For testing Keyword is  ::: "+keyword);

    result = search.searchCustomer(keyword);
    String table = "in here i'll generate a code to draw a table using html"

    Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        data.put("messageRes", table);


    // Write response data as JSON.
    response.setContentType("application/json");
    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    response.getWriter().write(new Gson().toJson(data));    
}

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
throws ServletException, IOException {

    doGet(request,response);

}
```

---

Now the problem is after i press the search button the searching process or the doGet method run 2 times.

In 1st run output 
"For testing Keyword is  ::: john "
2nd run
"For testing Keyword is  ::: "

I think that the 2nd run is happening because of "$.getJSON()" method.
How to avoid this ?

How can i use $.getJSON() method only to get the "String table" but not to run the "doGet()" method ?

Is there another way to get a string from servlet to jsp using ajax ?

Can i pass this keyword using $.getJSON() method ?

Thank you !

Comment: The `.getJSON()` is certainly making another call to the servlet, but in that particular request it's not sending a key. So that totally explains the second run with no keyword in the output. Do you not want it to go back to the servlet at all? If not, what was the original intention of the `.getJSON()` method so that someone can help you figure out what needs axing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use shorthand  AJAX call.

```
var keyword = $("#customerName").val();

$.get("SearchingClass", {key:$keyword}, function(data) {

            $("#resultTable").html(data.messageRes);
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not 100% following the code, but I'm *imagining* that you only want to query the servlet once, with the keyword you're passing it. The `.ajax()` method is therefore already doing the same job as `.getJSON()` which is just an alias for `.ajax()` anyhow.

Shot in the dark, but my guess is that you want this:

```
// ...
}).success(function(data) {
    $("#resultTable").html(data.messageRes);
  });
// ...
```